# Read CSV file from Specific Row i

Tags: vb.net

I am reading my CSV file like this:

Dim sData() As String
            Dim arrName, arrValue As New List(Of String)()

```
        Using sr As New StreamReader(txtFileName.Text)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                sData = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)

                Dim Curdate As String = sData(0).Trim()
                Dim OrderId As String = sData(1).Trim()
                Dim Exhbitorname As String = sData(2).Trim

            End While
        End Using
```

in my csv file first row is the column header.i dont want to read that values.i want read values from 1 st row,so how i can re write my code?

Comment: no sir.if i use SData(0) .i am getting first row and first column data.if i use Sdata(1) i am getting first row second column data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
You need to read the line before evaluating the counter value.

```
    Using sr As New StreamReader(txtFileName.Text)
        Dim counter as Integer = 0
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            sData = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)
            If counter > 0 Then
               Dim Curdate As String = sData(0).Trim()
               Dim OrderId As String = sData(1).Trim()
               Dim Exhbitorname As String = sData(2).Trim
            End If
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: this is worked fine.thanks,sir in browse button i giving code like this:Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
            With dialog
                .Filter = "Excel files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel files(*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            End With

Comment: how i can give code in browse button while uploading csv

Comment: Please, you could open a new post for your new query? Need more information to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 Using sr As New StreamReader(txtFileName.Text)
Dim rowCounter As Integer = 2
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
  If rowCounter > 2 Then
                sData = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)

                Dim Curdate As String = sData(0).Trim()
                Dim OrderId As String = sData(1).Trim()
                Dim Exhbitorname As String = sData(2).Trim
 End If
rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            End While
        End Using
```

Here what I have done is introduced a counter and initialized it with 0. I keep checking its value before each read and increment after the read. If the value is 0, meaning pointer is on header row , so just skip it.

```
CAMPAIGNNAME,PROMOCODE,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO,COUNTRYGROUP1,PERCENTDISCOUNT1,FLATDISCOUNT1,COUNTRYGROUP2,PERCENTDISCOUNT2,FLATDISCOUNT2,COUNTRYGROUP3,PERCENTDISCOUNT3,FLATDISCOUNT3,ACTIVE,NOOFHITS,APPLICABLEON
WELCOME,Twinkle,28-08-2015,28-08-2015,Bahrain_China,5,0,Europe_France,0,6,HongKong_Indonesia,5,,1,20,both
TRANSPORTER,Turkey,31-08-2015,31-08-2015,Bahrain_Mauritius_Netherland_Oman,20,0,France_Germany_HongKong_Indonesia,30,0,Italy_Kenya_Kuwait_Malaysia,30,,1,200,newsim
```

Comment: yes sir,,i tried this code only.first time that s skipping.but second time that is reading column header.third time only taking my value

Comment: paste your csv file with dummy values please

Comment: sir is ther any way to upload my csv file?

Comment: put it somewhere on pastebin

Comment: sir really i dont know how to put in pastebin

Comment: I Have Pasted .can you Please check

Comment: I do not think that is a CSV , I have added  a sample CSV data in my answer